# Scala 2.10 Storm Project ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, apache-storm

I suspect that this may be some sort of versioning issue, but still can not get to the bottom of it.
I am trying to set up a play2.1/storm project in Scala 2.10, with a Scala DSL based on https://github.com/velvia/ScalaStorm.
I copied and edited the DSL files into my project.
My problem arises when trying to implement the WordCountTopology example from the same project.
A direct copy/paste of the example compiles fine, and eclipse doesn't complain about anything, but when running the main function, I get classNotFoundExceptions

The classes are clearly defined, and commenting out the lines that use them (the builder.setSpout and builder.setBolt lines) and just creating new objects of the ClassNotFound classes (RichStormSpout, WordCount, SplitSentence), though it doesn't do anything, compiles and runs just fine.

Any help is much appreciated

edit:
here is a stack trace:

```
│java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: storm.WordCount                                                                     
│        at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:70) ~[storm-0.8.2.jar:na]                                                                                              
│        at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.getSetComponentObject(Utils.java:199) ~[storm-0.8.2.jar:na]                                                                                                               
│        at backtype.storm.daemon.task$get_task_object.invoke(task.clj:56) ~[storm-0.8.2.jar:na]                                                                                      
│        at backtype.storm.daemon.task$mk_task_data$fn__3766.invoke(task.clj:158) ~[storm-0.8.2.jar:na]                                                                               
│        at backtype.storm.util$assoc_apply_self.invoke(util.clj:731) ~[storm-0.8.2.jar:na]                                                                                           
│        at backtype.storm.daemon.task$mk_task_data.invoke(task.clj:152) ~[storm-0.8.2.jar:na]                                                                                        
│Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: storm.WordCount                                                                                                                         
│        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) ~[na:1.6.0_35]                                                                                                     
│        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_35]                                                                                                 
│        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_35]                                                                                                 
│        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_35]                                                                                                      
│        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_35]                                                                                                      
│        at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53$$anonfun$55$$anon$2.loadClass(PlayCommands.scala:535) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: You are running this in a play application, how are you kicking everything off?  I'm confused in reading your description, it said you are running a main function.

Comment: the reason is that https://github.com/velvia/ScalaStorm have compiled only for 2.9.x and not for 2.10.x